# Which NXP ARM processsors have LIN capability?

Tags: microcontroller, arm, lin

I am looking for potential alternatives for my current STM32F091 uC (they currently can provide a very lousy stock).

Searching through datasheets and reference manuals, **I can't pinpoint where to look when I want to find NXP uC-s that have LIN protocol capability.** DigiKey suggests that only **MK22FN 1M0 AV LK 12** has LIN but I couldn't confirm that in the [Datasheet](https://community.nxp.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nxp.com%2Fdocs%2Fen%2Fdata-sheet%2FK22P64M120SF5V2.pdf).

I am more interested in low pin count and/or small footprint uC, 64...80 WLCSP, QFN...

So any ARM uC family will do. ARM and KEIL support is more crucial.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I'd recommend simply calling an NXP sales representative. Their job. (although you might be small fish. But generally, these folks are happy to sell you their devices -> provisions)

Comment: Mouser seem to have plenty in stock and deliver to Estonia. Redesigning due to sourcing problems sounds like you need to sack your purchasing department! https://www.mouser.com/_/?keyword=STM32F091&utm_source=eciaauthorized&utm_medium=aggregator&utm_campaign=viewall&utm_term=STM32F091

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've now used the NXP community as well.

Comment: @DiBosco heh, BGA packages are out though. Could change the package, although again... redesign.
Although STM seems to have some general production issues, most distributors (DigiKey, Farnell, Mouser, Avnet...) are out of some certain packages and Lead Times for 1k+ stocks are quite ridiqulous.

Comment: Are you saying you designed it already with the BGA package?

Comment: @DiBosco Jup, due to few reasons. LQFP is just taking too much space for me though. Some 48pin is quite max. Anyway I've found some possibilities now - idea was to change the STM series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting answer from NXP support forum, one should look for Reference Manual and search for "break character transmission / detection " parameter under U(S)ART - which would tell if the uC has LIN capability (not all give results for keyword LIN).

So Determine other parameters first (CAN, USB, ... etc) and then check if the uC also has these conditions under UART.

I mentioned it was a bit tedious to mention LIN capability like so - I didn't know that "break condition" would determine LIN capability (silly me?). Having "LIN" directly in the manual would vastly ease the search and confirmation process.

So that's that.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea about what specifications other than NXP and LIN bus that are important for you (and neither has anyone else, seeing as that is not specified in the OP), but what I can say is that it is very easy to get a rough estimate of what processors to look for, and which of them that are in stock at what distributors.


[Go to octopart.com, choose ICs, filter on NXP, filter on Processors and Controllers and filter on LIN interface, and choose to view only "In Stock"](https://octopart.com/search?category_ids=4215&specs2.154.values=LIN&start=0&manufacturer.displayname=NXP%20Semiconductors)

Comment: But how often do you trust the distributor's parameters? I've seen them vastly under described and most can be faulty. So searching for them is as accurate as thorougly they have succeeded to fill in the description box.
f.i to search in DigiKey, I had to export the entire list to excel (probably only site that enables this) and then do String search on which has LIN and which doesn't. Otherwise it's impossible to filter these.

Comment: My experience with octopart is significantly better than some of the distributors when it comes to more complex parts. They're not only a search scraper, they do some more filtering on their own. Anyway you get search results sorted on some sort of intersection between all the different distributors filtering mechanisms. I'm not saying octopart will give you a definite answer, but it will for sure help you narrow down your population.

Answer (score 2):

Realistically, you can use any micro that has a UART. Just grab a transceiver. You're need to do that in most cases any way to comply with the physical layer requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Atmel (now Microchip) has ARM parts with LIN.

In general I would put their commitment to long-term availability of parts as better than NXP (just designing an NXP part out now, so it does have an upside for some of us).